# Breaking Circular Dependencies between MVC objects in Cocoa iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa, testing, model-view-controller, tdd

Hello fellow Stackers,

I am trying to use TDD to implement MVC in an iOS app, but I keep getting circular dependencies between models and controllers as well as between controllers and views.  I want to closely match the Cocoa MVC pattern shown in fig. 7.2 of the Apple docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html).

The problem arises out of my tdd requirement to init: all MVC objects with all of their dependencies. I need to init with all dependencies so mocks can be substituted during testing.  Here is a simple example of my issue.

View:

exampleView.h

```
//exampleView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "exampleViewController.h"

@interface exampleView : UIView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andVC:(exampleViewController *)VC;

- (void) updateLabelText:(NSString *)newText;

@end
```

exampleView.m

```
//exampleView.m
#import "ExampleView.h"
#import "ExampleViewController.h"

@interface exampleView ()

@property (nonatomic) UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic) UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic) exampleViewController* VC;

@end

@implementation exampleView
// use your imagination...
@end
```

Controller:

```
//exampleViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ExampleModel.h"
#import "ExampleRootView.h"

@interface ExampleViewController : UIViewController

- (id) initWithView:(exampleView *)view andModel:(ExampleModel*)model;

- (void) userActionButtonTapped();

@end
```

model

```
//exampleModel.h
#import "exampleViewController.h"
@interface exampleModel : NSObject
-(id)initWithVC:(UIViewController *)VC;
//other model type stuff

@end
```

Now the trouble comes when trying to init any of these objects. Because they are circularly dependent, its sort of a chicken and the egg scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way of designing MVC systems is for things to depend "downward" or "sideways" (e.g. View depends on controller, controller depends on model, model only depends on other models). This gets fudged a little bit with view controllers in Apple's frameworks, but is still broadly applicable. Having the model depend on the controller is the odd thing here — why is that necessary? It sounds like there might be some unnecessary coupling.

Comment: yes that will work, but I can't sacrifice the ability to mock views in VCs and mock VCs in models during testing.

Comment: @BKTurley: I'm not sure I follow. If your model doesn't depend on the VC, you don't need the ability to mock it. The necessity of mocking the VC in the model is an effect of the coupling there.